# Error message dialog at every startup: ""Load catalog:/self-product-catalog.setup"

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-mars

Every start of Eclipse I obtain the below Error:

```
Load catalog:/self-product-catalog.setup" has encountered a problem:
An internal error occurred during: "Load catalog:/self-product-catalog.setup"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible you are usig Eclipse from other pc/laptop.

Change configuration file (config.ini) in your `eclipse/configuration` folder using full (or correct) path.

I think that will work.